# Spring Boot Rest API runs from Eclipse but throws TypeNotPresentException in Tomcat8

Tags: spring-boot, war, tomcat8

I have a Spring Boot REST API application that works exactly as expected from Eclipse IDE. I `clean install`ed all custom dependencies, and `clean package`ed the REST to create a WAR file. While deploying this file on Tomcat8, I get following error message:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)

2016-05-26 12:28:49.001  INFO 6432 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.a.r.c.CardServiceApplication           : Starting CardServiceApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on Powerbox with PID 6432 (started by Parikshit in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\bin)
2016-05-26 12:28:49.008  INFO 6432 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.a.r.c.CardServiceApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-05-26 12:28:49.064 ERROR 6432 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration not present
        at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.java:46) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:84) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.annotation(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils$AliasDescriptor.<init>(AnnotationUtils.java:1951) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils$AliasDescriptor.from(AnnotationUtils.java:1936) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAttributeAliasNames(AnnotationUtils.java:1626) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAttributeAliasMap(AnnotationUtils.java:1539) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.postProcessAnnotationAttributes(AnnotationUtils.java:1175) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getMergedAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:382) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:117) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:280) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:90) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:70) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:146) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:127) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:122) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:158) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:126) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:708) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:357) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:439) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:420) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:599) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:597) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getAnnotation(Executable.java:570) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation(Method.java:622) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils$AliasDescriptor.from(AnnotationUtils.java:1931) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Here's my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.pp.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>cardservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>cardservicerest</name>
    <description>CardService REST API</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.pp.rest.cardservice.CardServiceApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pp</groupId>
            <artifactId>DAO-Commons</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pp</groupId>
            <artifactId>carddao</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pp</groupId>
            <artifactId>cardtemplatedao</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pp</groupId>
            <artifactId>cardlibrarydao</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. And the exception message is way longer than what I posted here.

Comment: Somewhere in your coe you are using a test annotation. Check where you have `@COntextConfiguration` in your code and fix that class.

Comment: i have not used @ContextConfiguration annotation anywhere in the project. However, I have a @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = CardServiceBeanConfig.class) on my main application class

Comment: Well don't... As `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` is test class.

Comment: i removed @SpringApplicationConfiguration from my main application class and it worked!!! Thanks!!